# CMakeLists.txt for when the executable is in a different folder than the source

Tags: cmake

I want to build a project with the following structure, but I am unsure as to the correct contents of the CMakeLists.txt files. the structure is this:

```
.
|- build 
|- src
| |- file.h
| |- CMakeLists.txt
|- test
|  |-main.c
|  |- CMakeLists.txt
|CMakeLists.txt
|
```

./src/file.h contains some function that ./test/main.c calls.
./build contains the generated executable.
I am using shared libraries, so you will see those in the `target_link_libraries` lines, but I excluded that from the problem to simplify the problem to its basic form...

the CMakeLists.txt of each folder is:

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

PROJECT(examples)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

**./src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(src C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(target_name main)
add_executable(${target_name})

target_include_directories(${target_name} PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} # Applications/Source
)
target_link_libraries(${target_name} pico_stdlib FreeRTOS-Kernel FreeRTOS-Kernel-Heap4)
```

**./test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(my_main C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(target_name main)
add_executable(${target_name})

target_include_directories(${target_name} PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} # ./Source
)

target_link_libraries(${target_name} pico_stdlib FreeRTOS-Kernel FreeRTOS-Kernel-Heap4)
```

Currently, running `cmake ../` from `build/` generates errors, and I do not know enough about CMake or about build systems to troubleshoot effectively, so I would appreciate corrections on the contents of ./src/CMakeLists.txt and ./test/CMakeLists.txt, and explanations about why to use which functions.

the errors:

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:30 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "main" which is not built by
  this project.


CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:35 (target_compile_definitions):
  Cannot specify compile definitions for target "main" which is not built by
  this project.


CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:38 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "main" which is not built by this
  project.
```

Comment: "currently, running cmake../ from build generates errors" - Add these errors into the question post. Make also sure that you have searched for these errors.

Comment: These errors are definitely not from the code you show us. Currently, both `src/CMakeLists.txt` and `test/CMakeLists.txt` defines the same executable target `main`, but don't assign any source file for it. This has no sense. If you are very beginner in CMake, then you are better to read some tutorial about it. E.g. the [official one](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev you were right! But I didn't know they weren't from the example I showed (long story short, the configuration I had worked UNTIL I added the test directory, then it errored).  
Also, I have tried reading the documentation multiple times but there is so much terminology I do not know and I have not been able to get a non-trivial example to work. This makes it difficult to ascertain what is incorrect and improve my understanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: some people are of the position that whenever you call [the `project()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html), you should be making that directory's CMakeLists.txt describe a standalone-capable project- one that handles as much of build, test, install, packaging, as needed.</sup>

I'm totally confused as to why both your ./src/CMakeLists.txt and ./test/CMakeLists.txt have almost exactly the same content. The `main` target should and must only be defined once in a buildsystem, which is true for your subdirectory projects (which- again- I don't understand why you have as their own `project`s), but not true for the top-level project.

Currently, what your file tree diagram suggests to me that you want is actually for the source directory to be for a header-only library, and for the test directory to define an executable testing that library.

<sup>If you actually want the source to define a static or shared library or an executable, then you should have a corresponding `.c`/`.cpp` file for the header file in there.</sup>

Here's what I'd do given that assumption of what you're trying to do:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11) # I'd look into using target_compile_features instead
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(examples C CXX ASM)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(my_library INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(my_library INTERFACE .)
target_link_libraries(my_library INTERFACE
  pico_stdlib
  FreeRTOS-Kernel
  FreeRTOS-Kernel-Heap4
) # assuming these are all required for any/all usage of my_library
```

the use of `add_library(<name> INTERFACE ...)` is for header-only libraries (libraries that by themselves do not compile to anything that you later link to). See [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) for more info.

test/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(my_test main.c)
target_link_libraries(my_test PRIVATE my_library)
# target_link_libraries any libraries to my_test any libraries that
# are required for it, but not for any/all usage of my_library
```

Comment: thank you, @user! that worked perfectly and helped  me understand CMake more. I have tried reading the documentation multiple times but there is so much terminology I do not know.  having a working example to build on will be immensely useful. 
Thank you again

Comment: @user, I do not yet have upvote privileges, but I accepted it. When I do have upvote privileges I will be sure to upvote it!